# Connected with no internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, drivers, dns, wireless-router

recently I have a problem using my wifi connection: the problem isn't the slowness, but rather the fact that very often there is no internet. Even if other devices are perfectly connected to the wifi and don't encounter such problems, my laptop happens to tell "connected with no internet". This problem seems to occur much more often if the computer is "stressed" and many process are going on at the same time.
I tried looking out on the net, but I couldn't find solutions: I've already tried to update network wirless adapter driver (the one I have installed is "Qualcomm QCA61x4A 802.11ac Wirless Adapter"), but I've been said there are no new update available; I've tried to flush the DNS cache using the command ipconfig /flushdns; I've tried to move the Roaming Aggressivness option of the network wirless adapter driver from medium to medium-high.
In conclusion I'm sure this is a problem of the laptop, but I couldn't find any solutions. Does someone have any advice?

Comment: Have you tried right click on the wireless tray icon > troubleshoot problems?

Comment: Yes, the issue is solved but after a while it happens again. As soon as the problem will happen again I'll report the precise errors

Comment: If you do not have multiple access points, you should set the roaming agressivness to low. It will just scan for new Ap's needlessly. You should download drivers from the manufacturer, don't rely on windows to do it for you... if that doesn't help, clean your laptops cooling system. You have indicated this happens under stress/loading, this is a sign it's overheating

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try out your advices

Comment: DavidPostill, I've finally managed to search for problems using the troubleshooter and it says <"Wi-Fi" hasn't a valid IP configuration>, any ideas about why?